# Form upload errors in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, upload

I can translate form upload errors in codeigniter but Turkish characters don't appear.

for instance system/language/english/upload_lang.php includes

```
 $lang['upload_userfile_not_set'] = "Dosyadan gelen değişken bulunamadı.";
```

But ş,ğ,ı characters do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save file with `utf-8` encoding after edit

Comment: I solved this problem with saving file with utf-8 and withoud BOM